# Conditional cumulative and time series columns in R

Tags: r, time-series

## Overview

I am analyzing incidents of protest in a dataset in which each observation indicates a single protest. Each observation has information about the date, country, and protest group that participated. I am using **R**.

## Data

The data look like this:

```
Date          Country          Group
----------    -----------      ------------
7/1/2015      Algeria          Labour Union
7/10/2015     Algeria          Labour Union
9/15/2015     Algeria          Labour Union
9/9/2016      Benin            Political Party
10/1/2016     Benin            Political Party
10/2/2016     Benin            Political Party
10/3/2016     Benin            Political Party
```

## Objective

I want to do **two things**:

**First**, I am trying to create a variable that tracks the cumulative number of protests that each group has performed.

**Second**, I am trying to count the number of days between events per group.

I want the data to look like this:

```
Date          Country          Group            Cumul       Days
----------    -----------      ------------     ---------   ------
7/1/2015      Algeria          Labour Union     1           NA
7/10/2015     Algeria          Labour Union     2           9
7/15/2015     Algeria          Labour Union     3           5
9/9/2016      Benin            Political Party  1           NA
10/1/2016     Benin            Political Party  2           22
10/2/2016     Benin            Political Party  3           1
10/3/2016     Benin            Political Party  4           1
```

Simply put, I have no idea where to start. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: One of the `'Days' is not correct.  7/10/2015 to 9/15/2015, i get a count of 67

Comment: @akrun, thank you! fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to group by 'Country' , 'Group', create the 'Cumul' as the sequence of rows, while taking the `diff` of the `Date` class converted 'Date'

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Country, Group) %>%
   mutate(Cumul = row_number(), Days = c(NA, diff(mdy(Date))))
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   Country, Group [2]
#  Date      Country Group           Cumul  Days
#  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>           <int> <dbl>
#1 7/1/2015  Algeria Labour Union        1    NA
#2 7/10/2015 Algeria Labour Union        2     9
#3 9/15/2015 Algeria Labour Union        3    67
#4 9/9/2016  Benin   Political Party     1    NA
#5 10/1/2016 Benin   Political Party     2    22
#6 10/2/2016 Benin   Political Party     3     1
#7 10/3/2016 Benin   Political Party     4     1
```

---

or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(Cumul = .N, Days = c(NA, diff(as.IDate(Date,
            "%m/%d/%Y")))), .(Country, Group)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("7/1/2015", "7/10/2015", "9/15/2015", 
"9/9/2016", "10/1/2016", "10/2/2016", "10/3/2016"), Country = c("Algeria", 
"Algeria", "Algeria", "Benin", "Benin", "Benin", "Benin"), Group = c("Labour Union", 
"Labour Union", "Labour Union", "Political Party", "Political Party", 
"Political Party", "Political Party")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much - this is exactly what I needed. I really appreciate your help.